# Can't initialise a controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I'm trying to get started with Angular, but running into a very simple issue. I have 3 pages in my application (index.html, app.js and invite.js). Now, I seem to have successfully initialised the angular application and I can run the application (see the console.log in app.js).

The problem is - I'm trying to create another controller, and I'm testing it with a simple alert() function - but I'm not getting any response.

Could anyone help point out where I'm going wrong? I assume it's a simple issue!

Thanks in advance :)

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head ng-app="batchSparta">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Batch Inviter</title>
    <!-- CSS and Javascripts --> 
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="invite.js"></script>
    <!-- END CSS and Javascripts -->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="InviteController">
        <div class="well">
            Here you can bulk-invite users to your Sparta account.
        </div>  

        <div ng-click="alert()" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Alert</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (the logged message is successfully shown)

```
var app = angular.module('batchSparta', []);

app.run([

    function() {
        console.log("Angular is running!");
    }
]);
```

invite.js

```
app.controller("InviteController", function($scope) {
    $scope.alert = function($scope) {
        alert("Alert triggered");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have ng-app set on the `head` element, so when Angular bootstraps, it's initializing your app in an area where your controller isn't (and can't be) located.

This explains why you're seeing the `run` log; and yet, your controller doesn't work.

Unless your Angular app is meant to reside on only a portion of the page, you can safely set the attribute on the `html` tag to have it encompass the whole page:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="batchSparta">
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rsq9zBrZS0txZ0p7DfKe?p=preview)

Comment: There is one in the code in question, it's just in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry - just noticed and was about to update my answer